# How can I calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}\right)$?

Tags: limits

I want to calculate

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}\right)$$

with both functions $f$ and $g$ tending to infinity when $x$ goes to infinity. The answer is zero but is there a more mathematical solution than saying that the denominator is larger than numerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morally, the larger of the two functions should dominate both the numerator and the denominator.
This heuristic idea is a good starting point, as it suggests to study two cases.

First, observe that by convergence to infinity both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are strictly positive when $x$ is large enough.
Let us look at any such $x$.

If $f(x)\geq g(x)$, then $f(x)+g(x)\leq f(x)+f(x)$ and $f(x)^4 + g(x)^4\geq f(x)^4$, so
$$
\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}
\leq
\frac{2f(x)}{f(x)^4}
=
\frac{2}{f(x)^3}.
$$
Similarly, if $g(x)\geq f(x)$, we get
$$
\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}
\leq
\frac{2}{g(x)^3}.
$$
Either way, we have
$$
\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}
\leq
\frac{2}{\max\{f(x),g(x)\}^3}.
$$
It may look weird to have a maximum downstairs for an upper bound like this, but it is indeed what we get.

Which of the two functions is bigger may depend on $x$.
But the estimate we got holds in both cases, so it is valid for all $x$.
That was the whole goal of the case-by-case estimate.

Now you just need to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\infty.
$$
This should be a straightforward exercise.

In fact, it is not necessary that both $f$ and $g$ go to infinity.
They can even both fail to do so, as long as the maximum goes to infinity and both functions are eventually non-negative.
The alternative method below doesn't work with this relaxed assumption.

---

This is not the only way to go, of course.
I just wanted to give a method based on the idea that the bigger one dominates.
You can also start with the estimate
$$
\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}
=
\frac{f(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}+\frac{g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}
\leq
\frac{f(x)}{f(x)^4}+\frac{g(x)}{g(x)^4}.
$$
There is no single correct way to do it.
In fact, it's not a bad idea to see if you can do it several different ways.

Comment: I think you want to have $\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$ and not $\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$.

Comment: Why do you consider differents cases ? $$\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4} \leq \frac{f(x)}{f(x)^4}+\frac{g(x)}{g(x)^4}$$ is trivial and the result easily follows.

Comment: @Surb If $f$ is bigger, we get the estimate with $f$ downstairs. If $g$ is bigger, we get $g$. So yes, we indeed end up with $\max$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I know there are several ways to go about this problem. I just wanted to give a method based on the idea that the bigger term dominates.

Comment: Sometimes there is not a bigger term: $f(x) =2+ x^2 + \cos x; g(x) =2+ x^2 + \sin x$.

Comment: @JohnHughes But for every $x$ there is a bigger term. That was my point, but I should clarify it.

Comment: Ok, so if I get it correctly, your estimate in term of the max implies that we only need that one of $f$ and $g$ goes to $\infty$ which is weaker than OP assumption

Comment: @Surb Correct. That's actually a point worth putting into my answer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta But then you might want to have these functions nonnegative.

Comment: @Surb Yes, the two functions need to be eventually non-negative and the maximum needs to go to infinity. That will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le \left(\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}\right)=\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}\right) +\left(\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}\right)$$
$$ \le\left(\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x)^4}+\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)^4}\right) \to0 \text{ as }x\to\infty$$

Where in the last step I used $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$

Thus by the sandwich therem, $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}\right)=0$$

Comment: So $0<0$? Did you mean $\leq$?

Comment: ... this doesn't really make sense. You write $0<\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}... 
$, thus $0=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}...$. Furthermore, how can you be sure that $\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4}<\frac{g(x)}{g(x)^4}+\frac{f(x)}{f(x)^4}$?

Comment: @Surb I was trying to use the sandwhich theorem. I'll add the proof of the inequality wait (Note that OP said both the functions tend to $+\infty$ too)

Comment: @Surb $$\frac{f(x)}{f(x)^4 + g(x)^4} \leq \frac{f(x)}{f(x)^4}$$

Comment: @GabrielRomon good point!

Comment: @Surb $\frac{g(x)}{g(x)^4}\to 0$ is trivial because  $g(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$

Comment: Please remove all the $\lim$ signs. You don't know if the limit exists *a priori*.

Comment: @GabrielRomon ah yes, makes sense. I'll remove it

Answer (score 0):

We know, that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$$

Let $$h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$$
Of course
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=\infty$$
For large enough $x$ we have:
$$h(x)\leq f(x)+g(x)\leq 2h(x)$$
and 
$$h^4(x)\leq f^4(x)+g^4(x)\leq 2h^4(x)$$
Thus:
$$\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^4(x)+g^4(x)}\leq \frac{2h(x)}{h^4(x)}=2\frac{1}{h^3(x)}$$
and
$$\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^4(x)+g^4(x)}\geq \frac{h(x)}{2h^4(x)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{h^3(x)}$$

We have then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^4(x)+g^4(x)}\right)\leq 2 \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{h^3(x)}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^4(x)+g^4(x)}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{h^3(x)}=0$$
Thus, after the squeezing theorem
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^4(x)+g^4(x)}\right)=0$$